# Open right for front matter

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

My front matter (abstract, table of contents, etc) does not start on the right hand side despite my chapters doing so. How do I ensure that these pages also start on the right hand side? The latex code is below.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}

% Packages

\begin{document}
\include{0_Frontmatter/title}

\onehalfspacing
\pagenumbering{roman}

\include{0_Frontmatter/acknowledgements}

\include{0_Frontmatter/abstract}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{1_Introduction/chapter1}

% etc ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try including a `\cleardoublepage` before using `\include` in each of your front matter components (or as the first thing contained within the `.tex` file you're including). Otherwise, if this does not work, post the partial contents of (say) `title.tex` and `chapter1.tex` so it would be possible to assess what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 5):

Only `\chapter` commands issue automatically a `\cleardoublepage`; the `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures` command do also, because they issue `\chapter*`.

Other parts must be treated individually; for example, if you want your acknowledgments and abstract to be on an odd-numbered page, then put

```
\cleardoublepage
```

as the first command in the included file (or just before the relevant `\include` commands). So

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}

% Packages

\begin{document}
\include{0_Frontmatter/title}

\onehalfspacing
\pagenumbering{roman}

\cleardoublepage % not strictly required, since we are on page I
\include{0_Frontmatter/acknowledgements}

\cleardoublepage
\include{0_Frontmatter/abstract}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{1_Introduction/chapter1}

% etc ...

\end{document}
```

Note that a `\pagenumbering` command automatically resets the page number to 1.