# TOC, LOF and LOT won't start on right

Tags: table-of-contents, double-sided

The Table of Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables won't start on the right page (recto) even though I put an `openright` `documentclass` option. I tried `\clearpage` before each one, didn't work. The chapters are working fine though.

Preamble:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openright,final,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
```

Body:

```
\input{Preamble.tex}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{ruledsmallhd}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\setlength{\parskip}{0.7cm}

\chapter    

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the settings in my `Preamble.tex` I get the desired result.

Comment: OK, I think I missed the answer for [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45669/open-right-for-front-matter?rq=1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45669/open-right-for-front-matter?rq=1) ... to use `\cleardoublepage` before each one.